# scrolling doesn't work when alerview with textfield is called in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, scrollview, uialertview

I am trying to add UITextfield in UIAlertview, so that user can enter the required text and after the submit is clicked the respective datas must send to the webservice.

Viewcontroller is 320*600 frameset, so am having scrollview for displaying the entire content.

While running, when the 'next' button is pressed, alertview with textfield is displayed with no issues, but the moment i click the 'submit' button or 'cancel' button in the alertview, the viewcontroller's scrollview is not working, but the 'back' button in navigation bar for moving to previous controller works good.

Code for alertview with textfield is,

```
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender
{

UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter your changes"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Submit Changes", nil];

[message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

[message show];
}
```

What could be the reason behind this and why the scrollview is not working properly.

UPDATED:

The action for 'submit' button is,

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    UIAlertView *approval = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"Your request is updated " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [approval show];

    text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    NSLog(@"passed value %@",text);// text returns the entered value

}
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://*******************************"];

NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSString * log= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@&Action=Preview&deal=%d&status=%d,comment=%@",session,value,11,text];
 [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[log dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

if(connection)
{
    NSLog(@"Request for change");
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

}
```

Comment: r u sure without alertview your scrollview is working.Make sure r u changing any content size of scroll view on submit button press.

Comment: @iPhoneDev, ya scrollview is working fine without alertview, checked that.

Comment: From the above code it seems that if button index is not 1.Then you are doing some server connection.r u sure the app is responsive on that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the actions linked with the cancel and submit button.There might be some mistake in that otherwise the scroll view would have worked.

Comment: got struck with this issue after actions of submit button, so now checking it with alertview and the textfield, the actions are not being implemented yet.

Comment: if actions are not implemented than what are you doing on the click of submit button.If no actions are linked with the button and the button is pressed than the view will be blocked giving some error message.

Comment: even if the actions are being implemented the issue is yet the same. Just for checking where the problem arises, the actions are being commented for a while. More over no error message is returned while the scrollview gets struck, scrollview not working that moment

Comment: share your code then only its possible to know where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code.link the submit_pressed action to the submit button.On the click of submit a alert view will be popped up and the values will be send the the given url link.After the click of Ok on alert view the normal view will be shown.It has nothing to do with the scroll view.

```
-(IBAction)Submit_pressed
    {
        UIAlertView *approval = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"Your request is updated " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [approval show];

        text = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
        NSLog(@"passed value %@",text);// text returns the entered value

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://*******************************"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSString * log= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@&Action=Preview&deal=%d&status=%d,comment=%@",session,value,11,text];
     [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[log dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

     [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    if(connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Request for change");
        responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    }
```